# Dependency Injection through a setter

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns

Does Laravel have the ability to introduce dependency through a method?
For example, I have a controller that implements the `DoctrineWorkable` interface:

```
interface DoctrineWorkable {
    public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $manager);
}

trait EntityManagerTrait {
   protected $manager;

    public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $manager) {
        $this->manager = $manager;
        // Other work with $manager
    }
}

class TestController implements DoctrineWorkable {
    use EntityManagerTrait;
}
```

How to use the `setEntityManager` method in a service container? To get something like this:

```
if ($class instanceof DoctrineWorkable) {
    $class->setEntityManager(new EntityManager());
}
```

p.s. Sorry for the bad English ))

Comment: I think you might be looking for "binding"... maybe?  https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container#contextual-binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things a little bit. The controller is not a service, so it won't be passed as an object (at least on programmer controlled level). This means that you can and should control dependency injection yourself. So, according to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers), there are three options to point to the Laravel that your controller needs any dependencies:

**1. Constructor Injection**

If you want to ensure that some controllers always have entity manager available to them, you can create a parent class. But I actually don't see the real value in this, accepts maybe you use a couple of entity managers, and they have to be passed to the different controllers.

**2. Method Injection**

As not all actions in the controller usually use entity manager, it might be a valid option.

If you read the [laravel doctrine docs](https://www.laraveldoctrine.org/docs/1.3/orm/entity-manager) you can find there **another option**, that uses facade:

> You can use the facade to access the EntityManager methods

Anyway, in my opinion, *interfaces should be used to define a contract*, and not to define the availability of some internal functionality.

**Regarding `// Other work with $manager`:**

You can extend your entity manager on service provider level. There're also several options on how to do this. You can find them in the [documentation](https://www.laraveldoctrine.org/docs/1.3/orm/doctrine-manager).